# How can I check if a Stripe promo code is valid for a Product, prior to checkout

Tags: stripe-payments

This is an issue I am trying to solve with Stripe Elements.

For a Stripe coupon, I can choose to have it only valid for Applicable Products.

During checkout, I would like to know when a user has selected a product, if that code applies, so that I can present the correct discount on that product (and not other products).

When I retrieve a PromotionCode there is no way to see what product ids apply.   When I retrieve a Product, there is no details as to what Promo codes work with it.

Is there any way to validate the coupon beforehand against a product?

Answer (score 4):

For people using cURL, this works (assuming `promo_id` exists):

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/promotion_codes/promo_id \
  -u sk_test_redacted: \
  -d "expand[]"="coupon.applies_to" \
  -G
```

Redacted response:

```
{
  "id": "promo_id",
  "object": "promotion_code",
  "active": true,
  "code": "MYCODE",
  "coupon": {
    "id": "couponId",
    "object": "coupon",
    "amount_off": null,
    "applies_to": {
      "products": [
        "prod_id"
      ]
    },
    "created": 1621194680,
    "currency": "usd",
    "duration": "repeating",
    "duration_in_months": 6,
    "livemode": false,
    "max_redemptions": 1,
    "metadata": {
    },
    "name": null,
    "percent_off": 75.0,
    "redeem_by": null,
    "times_redeemed": 0,
    "valid": true
  },
  "created": 1621194680,
  "customer": null,
  "expires_at": null,
  "livemode": false,
  "max_redemptions": null,
  "metadata": {
  },
  "restrictions": {
    "first_time_transaction": false,
    "minimum_amount": null,
    "minimum_amount_currency": null
  },
  "times_redeemed": 0
}
```

If you want to directly use the coupon id, you can use this(assuming `couponId` exists):

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/coupons/couponId \
  -u sk_test_redacted: \
  -d "expand[]"="applies_to" \
  -G
```

Redacted response:

```
{
  "id": "couponId",
  "object": "coupon",
  "amount_off": null,
  "applies_to": {
    "products": [
      "prod_id"
    ]
  },
  "created": 1621194680,
  "currency": "usd",
  "duration": "repeating",
  "duration_in_months": 6,
  "livemode": false,
  "max_redemptions": 1,
  "metadata": {
  },
  "name": null,
  "percent_off": 75.0,
  "redeem_by": null,
  "times_redeemed": 0,
  "valid": true
}
```

Comment: Here's the link to the Stripe documentation about expanding responses: https://stripe.com/docs/api/expanding_objects

Answer (score 0):

When you create a Coupon, you can limit it to particular Products with the `products` array: https://stripe.com/docs/api/coupons/create#create_coupon-applies_to-products (say prod_123)

Then, you create a PromotionCode off that Coupon. For any CheckoutSessions created for Prices (that are created off the same Product prod_123), the PromotionCode will only be applicable to those CheckoutSessions. Checkout validates this PromotionCode automatically.

Comment: I should clarify, I am try to use Stripe Elements, not checkout

Answer (score 0):

So I contacted Stripe support team and I found out that some properties are not loaded by default
What I did was retrieving the Promotion Code and then making a new search for the Coupon, but asking for the applies_to field:

```
val params = mapOf("code" to code)
val promotionCode = PromotionCode.list(params).first()

val expandList = listOf("data.applies_to")
        val couponParams = mapOf("expand" to expandList)
        val coupon =
            Coupon.list(couponParams).data.first { it.id == promotionCode.coupon.id }
```

Reference:
https://stripe.com/docs/api/expanding_objects